# How to parse and print array in React-Native?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I'm trying to parse and print array to the console in react-native.
I have a problem with index and declaration probably, ı could not access and print my array.

I got my array in main.js but ı could not access m_uid,m_latitude,m_longitude

I will use this variables in MapView.Marker

[Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqDyH.png)

Code in main.js

```
<MapView.Marker
  coordinate={{
    latitude : "I want to use m_latitude here",
    longitude: "I want to use m_longitude here",
  }}
 />
```

Action.js

```
 export function AddMark (item){
    return(dispatch)=>{
    dispatch(markSuccess(item));
 }
}

const markSuccess = (markSuccess)=>({
    type: types.MARK_SUCCESS,
    markSuccess,
})
```

Reducer.js

```
const initialState = {
   location: {},
    markSuccess:[],
   error : null,
};

const mapsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.MARK_SUCCESS:
      return {
      ...state,
      markSuccess: action.markSuccess
    };
    default:
      return state;
    }  
  };

export default mapsReducer;
```

Array Output:

```
Object {
  "markLocation": Array [
    Object {
    "m_latitude": 52.1769247,
    "m_longitude": 21.0167011,
    "m_uid": "AWxA11i3TQfu3FBguknRsA1y9It2",
    },
    Object {
      "m_latitude": 52.1769243,
      "m_longitude": 21.0167014,
      "m_uid": "I37DYEJt9vbdDw78iPW0hC4DcuZ2",
    },
  ],
}
```

Main.js

```
render() {
  const { markLocation } = this.props;
  console.log("arr",{markLocation});
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ mapsReducer:{location,error,markSuccess}}) => ({
  markLocation:markSuccess
});

const mapDispatchToProps = { };

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Map);
```

I use react-native expo with redux.

Comment: I dont see enough code here to be able to decifer that you are declaring the variable correctly or passing props correctly. I do know that you shouldn't have the curly braces in your console.log(), they're unnecessary.

Comment: Hello, ı just want how can ı access this array how can ı print it for example
in foreach {  console.log(marklocation[0].uid)  } == will give uid output but ı cant access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are doing wrong because I can't see what props has nor can't I see where you create an array. But to create an array in react-native do the following:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        array:[],
    }
}
```

To manage the array I would suggest to attribute the value of state to a temporary "normal" variable, there are many ways to do this, this is for me the most simple and easy.

```
let array=this.state.array;
array.push('one more value');
this.setState({array})
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, ı updated my topic again. Can you check it again ?

Comment: Sorry for really late answer but it was worked for me thank you. :)